# What Scope would this be in java?

Tags: java, variables, scope, int

In java, when I declare a variable as follows,

```
int i = 0;
```

what scope would this be in, global, public, private, static? In other words, what would not adding specification for the scope, default to?

Comment: It all depends **where** this declaration is, of course. but there is no global scope, public and private are not scopes, but visibility modifiers, and static is not really a scope either.

Comment: [***package-private***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html). Assuming it would be legal to make it `public` or `private`. And ignoring global/static (because we can't say without more detail). You should ask one question at a time (and do some research first and explain how that did, or did not, help).

Comment: at class it would be package-private, at interface it would be public static final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What Scope would this be in java?

```
int i = 0;
```

- if the variable `i` is declared global to the class then it's
  package-private.
- if the variable  `i` is declared within a method then it's only accessible
  within the containing method.
- if the variable `i` is declared within a given interface then it's said to be
  `public static final` by default. this would be available to all packages given that the containing `interface` is also declared `public`.

Comment: Package-private isn't a scope. Neither are `static` or `final`. This does not answer the question.

Comment: Make what you want of it. I have clearly answered the question at hand. :)